# Transfer txt file from openwrt router to password protected ubuntu

Tags: command-line, networking, ssh

I have 2 pass one txt file from openwrt router to Ubuntu, and also I installed sshpass package in my router for these command.

```
sshpass -p password scp /root/dnslog.txt root@xx.xx.xx.xx:/home/
```

Previously these command was working like a charm, but now these doesn't works.

Is there any other way to transfer files to any linux machine from router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer in other way, I just stored whole content of my file(dnslog.txt) into a variable and from router side I wrote a script and call php file which is present on my server and then post value of that variable and split and stored in new file. If anyone want both files then just write it on comment, I will share it.